# makefile compiling with c++0x

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation

I have a program that uses string functions and requires to compile with c++0x.But I can't figure out how/where to put "-std=c++0x" my flag. I've only compiled using basic commands within makefile, so this is new to me. Here is my current makefile without the flag.

```
output: main.o rFunctions.o
    g++ main.o rFunctions.o -0 Recursive
```

Comment: It really doesn't matter where you put it. You can put it immediately after `g++`. I suppose you have an old version of the compiler that still calls it C++0x, instead of C++11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [CXXFLAGS](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) in your make file:

```
CXXFLAGS=c++0x
output: main.o rFunctions.o
    g++ main.o rFunctions.o -0 Recursive
```

You can also add extra flags there: `CXXFLAGS=-g -Wall -std=c++0x`